# Auto keyboard by using SendMessage

Tags: sendmessage

```
int VK_F_DOWN = GetVirtualKey('F', 0);
int VK_F_UP = GetVirtualKey('F', 1);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,L"Calculator.exe");

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, toascii('F'), VK_F_DOWN);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, toascii('F'), VK_F_UP);
```

It doesn't work on the Calculator.exe,however it can work on my visual studio when I change `hWnd` to `HWND(0xFFFF)`.
And I also already got a non-zero `hWnd`. What am I missing here? Like authority or something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you. For example, what does "TEST process" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [User Interface Privilege Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation). As the Wikipedia article explains, you can request the access you want in your application manifest.

That said, you should be using SendInput rather than SendMessage. See [one of Raymond Chen's blog entries on that point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).